# ¿Cómo reproducir con pocos puntos una gráfica generada por un electrocardiograma que está conformada por muchos puntos?

Tags: android, arduino, bluetooth

Estoy trabajando con un Electrocardiograma [ECG] que se conecta a un Arduino, el Arduino obtiene los datos de este y posteriormente envío los puntos que obtengo del ECG a una app Android que a su vez envía cada dato a una BD en un servidor. El inconveniente que tengo es que son demasiados puntos los que envía el ECG (1 dato cada ms) y cuando los envió a la app se me satura y deja de recibir datos por lo cual necesito enviar menos.

Intente reducir el número de puntos haciendo promedios cada cierto tiempo (cada 40 ms). De esta manera puedo obtener menos valores, pero la forma de la gráfica se me deforma de a como es la forma original.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi pregunta es: ¿De qué manera puedo hacer que una gráfica que está conformada por muchos puntos, la procese y me resulte una gráfica con menos puntos conservando la forma de la grafica original?

He leído que es posible con la transformada rápida de Fourier, pero no entiendo muy bien cómo funciona. ¿Alguien podría explicarme mejor su funcionamiento?  ¿Existe otra forma de hacerlo?
De antemano muchas gracias.

Grafica del ECG obteniendo valor maximo y minimo cada 40 ms
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Voto para cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque es sobre procesamiento digital de señales, no sobre un problema de programación.

Comment: No estoy de acuerdo con eso. Por no mostrar el código, por ser demasiado genérica, por tener mas de una respuesta ... vale, pero por no versar sobre programación, no estoy de acuerdo.

Comment: Eso no puede estar bien. En la gráfica 1, todos los datos pasan de 300. En la 2, apenas pasan de 220. Eso no cuadra.

Comment: @Trauma Si se que no cuadra, lo hice por que mi objetivo es reducir el numero de puntos que conforman la gráfica pero sin perder la forma de la señal, de momento fue lo que se me ocurrió para reducir el numero de puntos fue hacer promedios de cada 40 datos y aun que esto me reduce el numero de puntos considerablemente la forma obtenida no es la que deseo

Comment: Creo que deberías de hacer la media entre el mínimo y el máximo de ese rango de 40, o coger solo el mínimo, o solo el máximo.

Comment: O incluso la [mediana](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediana_(estad%C3%ADstica))

Comment: @Trauma Agregue como se ve la grafica con tomando el maximo o el minimo, pero como puedes ver la grafica no es igual que la original

Comment: Divide y Vencerás. 
¿Armar pequeños paquetes de puntos y enviarlos de a poco para que despues el server reconstruya la función antes de guardarla en la BD ?

Comment: Una alternativa es utilizando RDP (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer%E2%80%93Douglas%E2%80%93Peucker_algorithm)

Comment: Aqui te muestro un ejemplo que hube en javascript, http://jsfiddle.net/rnrlabs/9dxSg/ quiza te sirva de referencia.